# R prcomp PCA rotation incorrectly mirroring data

Tags: r, rotation, pca, mirror

Has anyone had any issue with R's prcomp PCA rotation function rotating THEN MIRRORING the data? When I use principle from the psych package, the rotation is correct. Also, when I do it manually with cosine angle, it is correct. But when I do prcomp, it mirrors the data after rotating it. prcomp has some nice visualizations that I want to use that principle does not have.

Correct rotation:

```
    principal(PCADataFrame, nfactors=2, rotate="varimax")
```

Incorrect (mirrored) rotation)

```
    prcomp(PCADataFrame,  scale = TRUE)
```

I want to use

```
    fviz_pca_biplot(res.pca)
```

to plot factor loadings, but this only works with prcomp. So if anyone knows of similar visualizations with principle, that would be helpful to.